# SharePoint 2010 Installer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, installation

Once the installer is started I can't click Install Prerequisites or Install SharePoint Foundation. The links doesn't work. Other links (e.x. Read the installaiotn Guide) works fine. No messages, no further screens just nothing. What happends? 
I tried to run Enterprise version and behavior is the same.
I do this on virtual machine with Win Svr 2008 and MS SQL 2008.

Comment: This question should be posted to [StackExcahnge.SharePoint](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I didn't know there is such Stack branch. Thanks!

Comment: Closing as off topic instead of migrating since this was already [cross-posted to SharePoint.SE](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12870/sharepoint-2010-installer).

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the prerequisites and your server version. Sounds like it doesn't like something about your environment.